# Echoing more than 1 id

Tags: php

I would like to echo more than 1 id from my database, how do I display more than 1 id in my index page?

My Function:

```
function query($sql) {
 global $conn;
 $results = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
 $rows = array();
 if(!is_bool($results))
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) 
         $rows['id'] = $row;
    return $rows;
}
```

My Index page:

```
<?php foreach($funds as $fund) { ?>

 <td width="87%" valign="top"><ul id="funds" class="bodycopy2" style="margin:0;">
  <li><?php echo $fund['fund']; ?><span class="price"><div align="center" class="h1"><strong><br />R123.45</strong> <br />as at <br />1 January 2012</div></span></li>
  <li><?php echo $fund['fund']; ?><span class="price"><div align="center"   class="h1">  <strong><br />R200.45</strong> <br />as at <br />1 January 2012</div></span>   </li>
  <li><?php echo $fund['fund']; ?><span class="price"><div align="center" class="h1">   <strong><br />R150.00</strong> <br />as at <br />1 January 2012</div></span></li>
 </td>
     </tr>

     </table>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: And the question now is .... ?

Comment: Don't know what the config has to do with your function. Also don't know how you use the query function. Also don't know what the question should be!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of ids like :

```
$rows['ids'][] = $row;
```

Then you can go through ids using

```
foreach ($rows as $id)
```

Or directly `$rows[] = $row` if you only keep id.

Answer (score 0):

You are always overwriting the same element `$rows['id'] = $row;`. You should do

```
$rows['id'][] = $row;
```

to display the id you should iterate on $rows

```
foreach($rows['id'] as $id){
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: @Dale after doing that you have to iterate over `$rows['id']`

Comment: @Dale i assume that you are calling the query() function and assign it's return value to a variable, like `$rows = query("your sql here");` after thatcall you can use `$rows` as i explained